# Cordova 5.3.3 Android Push-Plugin Eclipse - Missing packages

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

i installed the following plugin to my cordova project to receive push-notifications (and followed the given steps):
github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

I also installed all needed resources by the sdk manager (extras-> google play services, support repository+libraries etc.)

But unfortunately i get an error in eclipse:
The packages com.google.android.gms.gcm, com.google.android.gms.iid, android.support.v4.app are missing somehow.. (or cannot be resolved)

i don´t know what i´m doing wrong.. 
is there any step-by-step tutorial for implementing the push-plugin in a cordova 5 app?
or is there any solution to this?

thanks!!

Screenshots:

http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-11qbf4.jpg

and

http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-2i7ozz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

May be it would help you.
It is asking to add v4 support.
Try this:

- Right click on you project in eclipse
- Then select "java build path"
- Click on "libraries tab" then click on "Add external jar file"
- now you will get this v4 jar file in C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v4

> **NOTE :** if you cant find the AppData folder then make sure to change hidden
>   settings.

Comment: thanks for your reply! now some errors are gone :) but unfortunately the "import com.google.android.gms...."-statements still show an error.. is there an similar solution to this?

Comment: Could you please upload the screenshot, it would be helpful for me to understand more.

Comment: Hey! here the Screenshots: http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-1rysb8.png http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-2t9s09.png http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-308sdd.png thanks for your help!

Comment: guess i fixed it. adding also android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-ser‌​vices_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Recommended to start using IDE Andriod Studio for Phonegap to prevent further issues. Android SDK has changed to suit Andriod Studio. I have build a clean project and paste over the index.html in Andriod Studio. No errors at all and gradle will help build all the projects file with 1 click!